Ubuntu 24.04 password for every file I try to open
THis may sound like a broken record. This all started after I setup my backups to external drives. I have permissions and groups are unchanged. this makes no sense.
I have tried resetting permissions but everything is still broken ( requires password )
drwxrwxr-x  2 mike mike  12K Aug 11 13:35  MISC
-rw-rw-r--  1 mike mike 100K Aug  2 20:52 'Monthly Report.pdf'
-rw-rw-r--  1 mike mike    0 Aug 21 11:51 'New Document.txt'
drwxrwxr-x  3 mike mike 4.0K May 30 14:13  Online-Purchases
drwxrwxr-x 22 mike mike  12K Aug 11 13:50  PDF
drwxrwxr-x 45 mike mike 4.0K Aug 20 19:46  RADIO
-rw-rw-r--  1 mike mike 1.9K Aug 20 19:33  RSYNC-Backups.txt

I tried creating a test file , save it . closed the text editor. opened the file againand it requires my login password.

Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.
